# Wildfly 15 get EJBContext in Singleton from jax rs logged in user

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, javabeans

I want to get the caller principal in an singleton from the logged in user. the user is authenticating against the rest service with username/password

the security domain is in the jboss-web.xml in the war

```
<security-domain>application-security</security-domain>
```

The endpoint in the war is:

```
@Path("/message/{message}")
public class MyRessource
{  
   @EJB
   MySingleton singletonBean;

   @GET
   public Response resource(@PathParam("message") String message)
   {        
        singletonBean.printText(message);
        System.out.println("called from: " + ctx.getUserPrincipal().getName());
}
```

the singleton is in an own project, and is provided as dependency at the war.

```
@Stateless
public class MySingletonBean implements MySingleton
{

    @Resource
    EJBContext context;

    @Resource
    SessionContext ctx;

  public void printText(String text) {
      System.out.println(text + ":: EJBContext: " + context.getCallerPrincipal().getName() + "  SessionContext: " + ctx.getCallerPrincipal().getName());      
  }

}
```

my web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method-omission>OPTIONS</http-method-omission>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>Admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

standalone-full-ha.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:5.0" ...>
   [...]
   <security-domain name="application-security" default-realm="application-properties" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
      <realm name="application-properties"/>
   </security-domain>
   [...]
</subsystem>
   [...]

<http-authentication-factory name="application-security-http" security-domain="application-security" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
   <mechanism-configuration>
      <mechanism mechanism-name="BASIC"/>
   </mechanism-configuration>
</http-authentication-factory>
[...]

<security-domains>
   <security-domain name="application-security" default-realm="application-properties" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
      <realm name="application-properties"/>
    </security-domain>
   [...]
</security-domains>
[...]

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">
   <security-domains>
      <security-domain name="application-security">
         <authentication>
            <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required">
               <module-option name="usersProperties" value="file://${jboss.server.config.dir}/context-users.properties"/>
                <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file://${jboss.server.config.dir}/context-roles.properties"/>
             </login-module>
          </authentication>
     </security-domain>
     [...]
</subsystem>
[...]

<subsystem xmlns="urn:boss:domain:undertow"...>
    <application-security-domains>
        <application-security-domain name="application-security" http-authentication-factory="application-security-http"/>
    </application-security-domains>
    [...]
</subsystem>
```

But i always get anonymous as principals.

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Do you have any security configuration in your web.xml? Typically you will only see a Principal when the accessed resource has been protected by a security constraint.

Comment: yes, my web.xml contains the security-role, the security-constraint and the login-config.

Comment: Please add these snippets to your question

Comment: i added the web.xml content

Comment: Please show your security configuration in WildFly

Comment: i added the standalone-full-ha.xml content

Comment: Please add the output of `/subsystem=undertow/application-security-domain= application-security:read-resource(include-runtime=true)` when executed from the jboss-cli with your application deployed

Comment: i already had this, only forgot to add it. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three problems here:

1. `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">` is a legacy configuration element that does not link up with elytron;
2. You are completely missing the ejb3 security configuration;
3. Your EJB method is not protected with `@RolesAllowed(...)`.

I got a similar example working:

1. Create an *elytron* properties realm:

   ```
   /subsystem=elytron/properties-realm=DemoPropsRealm:add(groups-attribute=groups,\
      groups-properties={\
        path=demo-roles.properties,relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir},\
      users-properties={\
        path=demo-users.properties,relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir,plain-text=true})
   ```
2. Create an *elytron* security domain:

   ```
   /subsystem=elytron/security-domain=DemoDomain:add(\
      realms=[{realm=DemoPropsRealm,role-decoder=groups-to-roles}],\
      default-realm=DemoPropsRealm,permission-mapper=default-permission-mapper)
   ```
3. Create an *elytron* http-authentication factory that is mapped to our DemoDomain:

   ```
   /subsystem=elytron/http-authentication-factory=demo-http-auth:add(\
      http-server-mechanism-factory=global,\
      security-domain=DemoDomain,\
      mechanism-configurations=[{\
        mechanism-name=BASIC,\
        mechanism-realm-configurations=[{\
          realm-name=DemoApplicationDomain\
        }]\
      }])
   ```
4. Map an *ejb3* subsystem application security domain to our DemoDomain

   ```
   /subsystem=ejb3/application-security-domain=\
       DemoApplicationDomain:add(security-domain=DemoDomain)
   ```
5. Link an *undertow* subsystem application security domain to our http-authentication-factory:

   ```
   /subsystem=undertow/application-security-domain=\
       DemoApplicationDomain:add(http-authentication-factory=demo-http-auth)
   ```

   "DemoApplicationDomain" will be the realm name in the `login-config` element of the web.xml and the `security-domain` in the jboss-web.xml file.
6. Declare the permitted roles on your EJB method:

   ```
   @RolesAllowed("Admin")
   public void printText(String text) {
       System.out.println(text + ":: EJBContext: " + context.getCallerPrincipal().getName()
        + "  SessionContext: " + ctx.getCallerPrincipal().getName());      
   }
   ```

Example source is in GitHub at [jax-rs-basic-auth](https://github.com/sfcoy/jax-rs-basic-auth).